# Unique Identifier for Mobile Devices using Cordova and AngularJS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, angularjs, cordova

please don't make my post like as duplicate why because am totally confused with those post when i google it.
but i need your valuable statements and real time experience on  **How to get UNIQUE IDENTIFIER for iOS,Android and Windows Mobiles**
i have a scenario that when user login with UserName and Password i send details to server at same time i need to send Device UUID. By using device UUID and User Credentials am going to Restrict second user login when first user is already logged in(Active). but am confused with getting **iOS Device UUID** but wheen i seen in many post iOS is killing apps in App store when app is Accessing any UUID values.

please suggest me better way to  complete mytask.

[Link-1](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/)
[Link-2](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/03/apple-forcing-developers-to-ditch-unique-device-ids/)

sorry for my bad english....!!!

Comment: in iOS you can use `identifierForVendor` as a unique identifier

Comment: @Paulw11   may i know  identifierForVendor is unique when app is uninstalled and installed it again

Comment: If the app is uninstalled and re-installed on the same device you may get a new identifier value, but you should probably set your server so that a second log in, logs out the first rather than rejecting the second login, so a new identifier won't matter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Unique Device ID plugin](https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID).

Install it:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid
```

And use it:

```
window.plugins.uniqueDeviceID.get(function(uuid){
    console.log("Unique ID": +uuid);
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

This will give you a unique ID per device that persists between installs.

Note that on Android 6 it requires telephony run-time permission to access SIM ID. Also you may need to fork it and update it to get the Windows Phone 8 code working on Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

in the case of angular
you gotta install ngx-device-detector via npm then import it on your module and in the import section add DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot().then in the component you're gonna use import it and add private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService this in the constructor it will generate u a method and add it on the constructor this.epicFunction(), if it doesnt paste this

```
epicFunction() {
    console.log('hello `Home` component');
    this.deviceId = this.deviceService.getDeviceInfo();
    const isMobile = this.deviceService.isMobile();
    const isTablet = this.deviceService.isTablet();
    const isDesktopDevice = this.deviceService.isDesktop();
    console.log(this.deviceId);
    console.log(isMobile);  // returns if the device is a mobile device (android / iPhone / windows-phone etc)
    console.log(isTablet);  // returns if the device us a tablet (iPad etc)
    console.log(isDesktopDevice); // returns if the app is running on a Desktop browser.
  }
```

note: the "this.deviceId" is a variable i created in the start of the class

in the case of android just import the security and add the permission on the manifest file